# Strange Github network merge graph

Tags: git, merge, github

I have branch master, branch develop from master and branch test from develop. All 3 branches are from initial commit. In test I have two commits. I make `git checkout develop && git merge --no-ff`. Now in my master I have 1 more commit with merge results, nice. But at GitHub graph looks very strange:

[image: weird merge]

Have you any ideas? I do something wrong or github graph just sucks?

Comment: Which branch is which in the picture? How did you expect it to look? Does it display wrong / misleading information or is it just not as pretty as you expected?

Comment: `git merge --no-ff` is an invalid command -- you must specify a commit to merge.  Please fix your question and provide the exact commands you typed.

Comment: I'm very interested in how this style of graph gets created, too

Comment: possible duplicate of [GitHub network graph representing wrong first parent after merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647875/github-network-graph-representing-wrong-first-parent-after-merge)