# GitHub network graph representing wrong first parent after merge

Tags: git, github

I've found a discrepancy between the GitHub network graph and the git log.

Compare the [network graph](https://github.com/axsk/niagara/network) of my GitHub repository called [`niagara`](https://github.com/axsk/niagara)

[image]

to the output of `git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate`:

```
* 13d9ccc (origin/dev, dev) edit printState
* 32e4285 add support for different jewels
* 23f6c5d fix weather application
* 4236119 refactor
*   a731e72 (refactor) Merge branch 'fix' into dev
|\
| * 6d3ca43 (fix) fix winrate determination
| * 5f39b62 fix weather application to second boat
| * 8e2b813 fix win condition
| * 57fc73d fix win percentage
| * 48b8a0f fix possibleMove
|/
*   dabc470 (HEAD, origin/master, master) Merge pull request #1 from axsk/boats
```

**Edit**:
The first five nodes on the green branch correspond to the five consecutive fix commits (`48b8..6d3c`), which I commited in the (local) `fix` branch, whose head is at `6d3c`. 
I then merged the `fix` branch to the `dev` branch with `--no-ff`. This is correctly displayed in the output of `git log`, but GitHub just shows the green curved arrow instead of a separate branch for the `fix` commits.

Am I getting something wrong or is this some kind of bug on GitHub's side?

Comment: Could you elaborate what's wrong? GitHub's graph doesn't show commit hashes so it's a bit difficult to compare the two.

Comment: @musiKk That curved green arrow makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Jubobs That's probably a merged pull request consisting of one commit.

Comment: @musiKk The [only pull request listed](https://github.com/axsk/niagara/pull/1) (now closed) does not involve any of the two commits related to that green arrow.

Comment: @Jubobs OK, but it's still a non-fast forward merge with one commit.

Comment: @musiKk I can't make sense of your last comment.

Comment: @musiKk i think a no-ff merge with one commmit should rather look like like a triangle with a vertex on top, which is missing here.
And as you can see from the `git log` there is no one-commit-merge.

@Jubobs thank you for the pictures

Comment: @axsk For information, I've sent an email to support@github.com about this, but they haven't got back to me yet. I'll let you know if I ever hear from them.

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks :) I've done the same but also got no answer yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're right: something is off. In particular, that curved green arrow seems to indicate that commit `6d3ca43` is "*twice*" a parent of commit `a731e72`, which makes no sense.

[image]

[image]

---

As far as I know, there is no way, in Git, for a commit to have *two* parents that are actually one and the same. Even if you're in the following situation (and your working directory is clean),

```
o -- o [master=HEAD,develop]
```

running

```
git merge --no-ff develop
```

is a no-op: the output of that command is simply

```
Already up-to-date.
```

Conclusion: my feeling is that it is a bug on GitHub's side...

---

**Update**: I contacted GitHub's support about this and they got back to me. Read below.

> Thank you for calling our attention to that network graph -- I agree that looks confusing. I've opened an internal issue to let our team know about this, and we'll get back to you as soon as we have more information.

Comment: You're right. The green arrow should start four commits to the left.

Comment: Did they ever get back to you?

Comment: @AndyHayden No, never.

Comment: @axsk If you can, try to find a sequence of operations that reproduces the problem and report here.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred for me. Previously the horizontal line in blue on the image below was exhibiting this behavior (like the green quirk in the question). However, doing the back merge (purple line into black, then re-merge into develop) caused the blue line to appear correctly (maybe has something to do with having the same start point as the black line).[image]

EDIT: After further testing and seeing this bug many times in practice, I've noticed that new commits (esp. merge commits that cause the graph to be re-drawn in a new configuration) will often clear the issue and draw the errant branch correctly, with the correct parents. One doesn't necessarily have to back-merge to fix this. Reassuringly it appears to be purely a graph issue rather than any issue with the underlying commit history.

Comment: Am suspicious that Git's algorithm may simply be drawing lines over each other.