# How do I fix this git network graph?

Tags: git, github, merge

I'm applying the branching model that @nvie describes in his [article](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). With one change; I use a `staging` branch where I test and build pre-releases before they get merged into `master`.

So I have `develop -> staging -> master`. Where changes from `develop` get merged into `staging` (as `0.1.0-pre` for example), tested and then if everything's good merged into `master` (in this case as `0.1.0`).

My network graph for the following workflow looks like this:

[image: network graph]

The weird thing though is that the commits on `develop` show up in the graph as commits on `staging`. My intention was to have all commits show up on `develop`, with merge arrows from `develop` to `staging` for the prereleases, and merge arrows from `staging` to `master` for the releases (which is currently the case).

So how do I get my network graph / git history to resemble the `develop -> staging -> master` model?

Comment: As long as staging and develop do not diverge they are the same for git, just different branch names for the same commits.

Comment: This GitHub graph is broken in a way similar to that in the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647875/github-network-graph-representing-wrong-first-parent-after-merge

Comment: @ckruczek But staging was branched from develop's initial commit (as was master). Why does the network graph choose staging as the base branch when develop diverges and not vice versa?

Comment: Ah ok, that wasn't clear at first. So then I think the link @Jubobs posted might help you.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it. So basically it's a github bug? No way to solve it?

Comment: @ckruczek Take a look at this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD1SG.png, a git log of the starting point of my history. Note that develop isn't there. Even though it's the starting point of my history. I don't think it's a github bug.

Comment: Develop isn't there because develop moved forward in time because you alreade developed on it. Maybe you open `gitk --all` and view the structure there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it corrected itself after another set of merges (with the exact same strategy). So it seems nothing needs to be done.

[image: branch graph]